# MATLAB - Sort struct by substruct field

Tags: matlab, sorting, struct

I'm a new Matlab user and a I have some doubts about structs.

My case is:

I have a struct P1 that have 3 "substructs"( A1, A2, A3) with two fields(Name and Age) and I want to sort my "substructs" by age. So, I have it:

```
P1.A1.age = 33
P1.A2.age = 23
P1.A3.age = 31
```

and I want this results:

```
P1.A2.age = 23
P1.A3.age = 31
P1.A1.age = 33
```

Any idea?

I try to use the function orderfields, but I didn't have the results that I wish.

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get the required permutation for sorting using `sort` and `structfun`. Then apply that permutation using `orderfields`:

```
[~, I] = sort(structfun(@(x) x.age, P1));
P1 = orderfields(P1, I);
```

Comment: Did not know about those 2 functions! +1

Answer (score 0):

Will this work for you?

```
>> [val idx]=sort(arrayfun(@(x) P1.(sprintf('A%d',x)).age,1:3))

val =

    23    31    33


idx =

     2     3     1
```